# Get headers from $q.all $http requests

Tags: angularjs

I'm running a bunch of http requests with the method below, but unsure how to get the headers as per the example provided. Any ideas?

```
var requests = [];
var queries = ['athing', 'another thing'];
angular.forEach(queries, function(value, key) {
  var queryString = "http://adomain.com/things?q="+value;
  requests.push($http.jsonp(queryString));
});

$q.all(requests).then(function(data) {
  //how to get headers for data[0] and data[1]?
  // data[0].headers returns some code I'm not sure what to do with
});
```

Bonus points on pointing me in the right direction for how to retry attempt depending on the returned header information.

It's important for me to keep these in order (data)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your headers are accessible for each of the response objects like so:

```
data[0].headers();
```

If you want to retry that particular request (but not the others) you're going to have to do that manually.

It might help to know that you can access the url for this call here:

```
data[0].config.url;
```

and access/modify your request headers here:

```
data[0].config.headers;
```

Comment: I had tried data[0].headers() however it returns an empty object, not sure why this is the case.

Comment: They should be there. I just tested this out on some of my own code. The fact that you're getting even an empty object is promising, though not very helpful yet. If you haven't already go it, install fiddler and it can tell you if your service is actually returning any headers at all: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Using fiddler, I can see that I'm getting headers back, but still unable to view the headers in my code. Also tried data[0].headers("Content-Type") with no luck

Comment: Also, were you using $http.jsonp in your tests?

Comment: No, my services use GET, POST and PUT. I did have a look around to see if JSONP would behave any differently, but couldn't find anything about that.
I'm out of ideas.